# Why did this explosion make me fat? (A land mine increased my weight)

Tags: nethack

```
You drop a dwarvish mattock. Your movements are now unencumbered.
You see here a tin. KAABLAMM!!! You triggered a land mine! Your movements are slowed slightly because of your load. You fall into a pit!
```

Why did this happen? I picked up some scale mail, and became burdened. So I dropped my dwarvish mattock (I still have a pickaxe). That un-burdened me. I walked over to a tin I saw and stepped on a land mine that was suddenly there! I fell into a pit, and then somehow I became burdened again. The tin, meanwhile, flew across the room. (Poor tin.)

How did the explosion increase my weight? Is this a kind of status effect? If so, how could I remove it? The [wiki article on land mines](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Land_mine) mentions nothing about this, and I don't have autopickup on (the tin flew away anyway).

Comment: Are you sure it increased the weight you're carrying, and didn't *reduce your capacity*?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, of course! Why didn't I think of that? Do explosions abuse Str or Con? In any case, that's probably it; you could post that as an answer.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Nethack; it was just a supposition from first principles of RPG experience is all.

Comment: You're reading the wrong wiki article; you want to follow the link to http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Trap#.5E_Land_mine to learn about the trap, as opposed to the item that can be applied to make the trap.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It did not increase your weight; it gave you [wounded legs](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Wounded_legs), which decreases your carrying capacity.  You'll get better after a few turns.

Comment: ...which also explains the mysterious "Your leg feels somewhat better" message I just got. Thanks!

Comment: Bah. I was writing in this same answer when yours popped up :P

Answer (score 3):

> Wounded legs is an intrinsic property generally considered undesirable. With wounded legs, your dexterity is reduced by one and abused every five turns. You are unable to jump, kick, or ride anything, **and you become significantly more burdened**. However, it is temporary, lasting usually only a few turns. After it is gone, your dexterity returns to its normal level and your encumbrance returns to its previous level.
>
> Legs may be wounded by:
>
> - An exploding land mine

From [the Nethack wiki](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Wounded_legs).